# Checkbox confirm message - Remain checked if false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently trying to add a JavaScript confirm message when a user attempts to deselect an option.

If a user selects cancel on the confirm screen the check box should remain ticked. The problem I am having is that the check box becomes unchecked even if I return false.

Code example can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/Amjzv/

HTML

```
<div class="ServiceDesc Alternate">    
    <span class="expandable">
        <input id="ctl01_chk" type="checkbox" name="ctl01$chk" checked="checked">
    </span>                
</div>​
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //each load to persist state
        $('.expandable').each(function () {
            ToggleCheckboxes($(this),false);
        });
        $('.expandable').click(function () {
            ToggleCheckboxes($(this),true);
        });
    });
    //toggle child checkbox show/hide
    function ToggleCheckboxes(checkboxSpan, showConfirm) {
        if (checkboxSpan.find(':checked').length > 0) {
            checkboxSpan.parent().find('.indent').show();
        }
        else {
            if (showConfirm) {
                var answer = confirm("Are you sure?");
                if (answer) {
                    checkboxSpan.parent().find('.indent').hide();
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else {checkboxSpan.parent().find('.indent').hide();}
        } 
    }​
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. All were valid but the accepted answer fixed the issue with the least effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning false inside your custom function, but not inside the function assigned to the click event. just fix the following line:

```
$('.expandable').click(function () {
    return ToggleCheckboxes($(this),true);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Simplest Way

```
$("#ctl01_chk").click(function() {
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")) { 
           // continue;
    } else { 
       return false;
    } 
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/Amjzv/16/)

Comment: +1 I think it was the change event that was the problem ... your `click` works much better ....but definitely the simplest way

Answer (score 3):

you should pass the `click` eventObject to your function so you can do

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Here's an [update](http://jsfiddle.net/Amjzv/14/0)

Comment: @Starx oeps forgot the return the true/false back here's an update http://jsfiddle.net/Amjzv/14/

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) rather than returning false ... you can do this by passing the `event` to the function that shows the confirm

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //each load to persist state
    $('.expandable').each(function () {
        ToggleCheckboxes($(this),false);
    });
    $('.expandable').click(function (event) {
        ToggleCheckboxes($(this),true,event);
    });
});
//toggle child checkbox show/hide
function ToggleCheckboxes(checkboxSpan, showConfirm,event) {
    if (checkboxSpan.find(':checked').length > 0) {
        checkboxSpan.parent().find('.indent').show();
    }
    else {
        if (showConfirm) {
            var answer = confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (answer) {
                checkboxSpan.parent().find('.indent').hide();
            }
            else {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        else {checkboxSpan.parent().find('.indent').hide();}
    } 
}​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Amjzv/17/)