# How to create a custom window pop up when chekcbox is clicked or unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have create the pop window when user click check-box. When the check box is clicked, I display the pop up with relevant message for user to confirm if the really want to click the check box. Same when the check box is checked and user want to uncheck it. I want to display the pop up with relevant message if the really want to uncheck the checkbox.

In few steps this what suppose to happen

1. If user clicks the checkbox, i want to show my custom pop up to ask user if they really want to check it. If user click YES, I check the checkbox. Else if they click CANCEL keep checkbox unchecked.
2. If user want to uncheck the checkbox, I want to also show my custom pop up to ask user if they really want to uncheck the checkbox. If they click YES uncheck the checkbox. Else if they click CANCEL keep checkbox checked.

[Here is my CODE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/9herrf9r/1/)

Sorry if this is a duplicate of asked question.

Comment: what problem did you encounter?

Comment: If the checkbox is ticked or unticked i get irrelevant message it display "sync_payments" as the message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show Javascript confirm box when checkbox is unchecked and then if user selects cancel, leave the checkbox checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208022/how-to-show-javascript-confirm-box-when-checkbox-is-unchecked-and-then-if-user-s)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904181/checkbox-confirm-message-remain-checked-if-false

Comment: Nirpendra Patel  did you read my question above? What makes my question to be duplicate from the reference you gave?

Comment: I think you calling the id on your `onclick="Confirm.render(id)"` that is why you are getting the message "sync_payments"

Comment: King is have removed this 

`if (op == "check_box") {
checkBoxPost(id);
}`

Now i get an undefined as a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured my problem by changing the code of my js

This is what i came up with

```
function CustomAlert() {
           debugger;
           this.render = function (dialog) {
               debugger;
               var winW = window.innerWidth;
               var winH = window.innerHeight;
               var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
               var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
               dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
               dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
               dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
               dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
               dialogbox.style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Acknowledge This Message";
               document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
               document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button >OK</button>';
           }
           this.ok = function () {
               debugger;
               document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
           }
       }
       var Alert = new CustomAlert();

       function CheckBoxConfirm() {
           this.render = function (dialog, op, id) {
               debugger;
               var winW = window.innerWidth;
               var winH = window.innerHeight;
               var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
               var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
               dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
               dialogoverlay.style.height = winH + "px";
               dialogbox.style.left = (winW / 2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
               dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
               dialogbox.style.display = "block";

               if ($('#sync_payments').is(":checked"))
                   document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = 'Are you sure you want to enable all device use?';
               else
                   document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = ' Are you sure you want to disable all device use?';

               document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Confirm that action";
               //document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
               document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Confirm.yes(\'' + op + '\',\'' + id + '\')">Yes</button> <button onclick="Confirm.no()">Cancel</button>';

           }
           this.no = function () {
               debugger;
               document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";

               if ($('#sync_payments').is(":checked")) { // checked

                   $("#sync_payments").attr('checked', false);
               }
               else {
                   $("#sync_payments").attr('checked', true);
               }

           }
           this.yes = function (op, id) {
               debugger;
               document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";

               if ($('#sync_payments').is(":checked")) { // checked
                   // leave as it is
               }
               else { // unchecked
                   $("#sync_payments").attr('checked', false);
               }
           }

       }
       var Confirm = new CheckBoxConfirm();
```

And changed my HTML checkbox to this :

```
<label for="sync_payments"><input type="checkbox" id="sync_payments" name="sync_payments" onclick="Confirm.render()"/> Enable for all devices </label>
```

And I got the output I was looking for.

Comment: Glad it did. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
            console.log("CCCCheckeddddddd");
            if(confirm("Hello")){
            //enter code here i.e mark your checkbox as checked
    }
       }
        else
            {
                console.log("UNCheckeddddddd");
     if(confirm("Hello")){
            //enter code here i.e mark your checkbox as unhecked
    }

}    
    });
```

Comment: `$('#sync_payments').change(function() {
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
            console.log("CCCCheckeddddddd");
            if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to enable all devices?'")){
           $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    }
       }
        else
            {
                console.log("UNCheckeddddddd");
     if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to disable enable all devices?")){
           $(this).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
}    
});`

This works but, can you please look at my code to improve it. I have put used your code on my custom pop up.

Comment: Your solution is working but is not what I m  looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Jay Star on the `onclick="Confirm.render(id)"` change that to this `onclick="Confirm.render()"`

On you onclick dont pass any parameter just call `confirm.render()`. Hope this will help you.